# insert to database and automatically update listview

Tags: android, database, android-activity, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

i ve created a project with a single activity in android and i want to add a new record to database by pressing "insert button" as i showed in picture, but i want as soon as the New record saved to database , ListView updates and show the added record to the list in the last position...

when i run this code unexpected error occures and it close
where is the error or any suggestion ...

[image]

i put all the codes and layout here...

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.db;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button Btninser;
SQLiteDatabase db;
EditText etName, etPhone;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    Btninsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Btninsert.setOnClickListener(this);
    Open_Create();

}

    public void Open_Create() {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB1", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LastName VARCHAR,Phone VARCHAR);");

}

public void Insert_Info() {
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MyTable (LastName,Phone) VALUES('" + etName.getText().toString()
            + "','" + etPhone.getText().toString() + "');");

    Populate_ListView();

    // db.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data has been saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void Populate_ListView() {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT LastName,Phone FROM MyTable", null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { "LastName", "Phone" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvItemListName, R.id.tvItemListPhone };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.item_list, cursor, from, to);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And here is the XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnInsert"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Insert" />

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I ve added the error from  DDMS also
as you can see in Error page It mentioned a field "**_id**" **that i never had it!!!!** :(
confusing me too much...

[image]

Comment: By "unexpected error" do you mean a crash? If so, please post the crash log. In any case, simply doing a `notifyDatasetChanged()` after inserting the new entry should tell the listview to update itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a Cursor, Android automatically assumes that your tables have a column called `_id` which acts as the row's unique primary identifier, for more details on that see the "Class Overview" section of the [CursorAdapter's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) which says:

> Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget. The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

Basically all you need to do is replace your `CREATE TABLE` call with:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, LastName VARCHAR,Phone VARCHAR);");
```

That should fix your crash. To get it to automatically refresh the list, see my comment regrading `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

And as a sidenote: I'd strongly recommend using a [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) instance to handle the opening and creation of your tables, rather than what you are doing now, it's bad form to repeatedly call `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` where you could only call it the one time you know it'd need to be called. [Vogella.com has a great guide on that](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Edit: Based on your last edit of your code: You're still not requesting the `_id` field that you made. If you don't have it in your SELECT statement the cursor can't access it!

Replace your `rawQuery` in `Populate_ListView` with `SELECT * FROM MyTable` so that the `_id` field is also returned by the cursor.

Comment: if i use this line of code again same error as before occur, _id is not exist!!!!

Comment: You haven't uninstalled your application and re-installed it since you modified your code, so your table isn't being recreated again since you're using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and your db already exists. Uninstall the app and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to delete `Open_Create()` call from `onClick()` method? You have two consecutive call to `openOrCreateDatabase()` without any `close()` in the middle. Don't forget the `try { ... } catch (SQLiteException) { ... }`. You test.

Comment: @kasra Rahjerdi i added the error as you said, now what s the problem?

Comment: Probably that column doesn't exist as suggested by console. However I don't reccomend you to use 'startManagingCursor(Cursor c)'. Read below:

"This method was deprecated in API level 11. Use the new CursorLoader class with LoaderManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package."

Comment: This class implements the Loader protocol in a standard way for querying cursors, building on AsyncTaskLoader to perform the cursor query on a background thread so that it does not block the application's UI.